# Redirection from http to https in Apache httpd24 with mod24_ssl is not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

I have my Amazon linux server and I had installed httpd24 and mod24_ssl. I had been setup ssl certificate in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file with https redirect instructions:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com:80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName example.com:443
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

But the `httpd` starts normally without any issue. But the redirection is not working. I have other file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`here. What I might have missed.? I come across many articles but those didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` line is superfluous, any traffic hitting that virtual host is going to be HTTP by definition. You probably also need a `RewriteEngine on` directive as well to enable `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Yes. Silly mistake by me. Thanks much. I did changed and redirect is happening now but its giving too many redirects while loading the page.